# My third rebus you probably see every day

Tags: rebus

I was to lazy to draw it myself, so I got my friend to draw it for me:
[image]

Comment: image isn't clear

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I'll make a better version later sorry

Comment: Do you mind processing your image before posting it? It's a 5 megapixel whopper that loads sluggishly. It also wastes a lot of space -- the rebus proper makes up only a quarter or so of the image. Mix in the blurriness, the "I was too lazy" preamble and the write-in solution, this puzzle does not make the impression that a lot of work and love have gone into it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> GRASS

because

> as mentioned by @rhsquared "grape" - "ape" = "gr".
>  And the third image I think is a "donkey" or [similar with "ass"](https://www.animalwised.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-donkey-a-mule-and-an-ass-188.html) so "gr" + "ass" = "grass"

and of course, you probably see it every day

Comment: I think you got it :)

Comment: If this is the answer then the last part of the image should have been something else if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

> It's obviously grape - ape so it starts with 'gr'. The third image though could be anything. It's so unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to rhsquared’s answer:

> The last one looks like a donkey, or an **ass**, so if you add **gp** as rh said, you get **gpass** or a **G pass**

Comment: Where did the gp come from?